# jQuery event capturing stop propagation

Tags: jquery, event-handling, stoppropagation

I have a event listener on a parent div, and i'd like it not to get fired on child div onclick as well.

I'm using jQuery for this, since i need the .on() being the element dynamically created, also the child div is dynamically created with an inline onclick="myFunction()".
When the onclick myFunction occurs in the child i don't want the parent .on(click) gets called again.

html:

```
    <div id="parent" class="areatext" onkeydown="checkR()">
    <div id="input" contenteditable="true" style="min-height:26px;" onkeyup="checkTyping()"></div>
    <div id="child" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
    </div>
```

js file 1:

```
$('#parent').on('click', function(event){
    $('#input').focus();
    console.log('parent clicked!');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

js file 2:

```
function myFunction(event){
   // actions
   // when this is clicked, #parent .on(click) also triggers, i don't want that
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, jQuery doesn't support listening to events in the capturing phase; you'll have to use standard Javascript instead of jQuery in order to accomplish that. For example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('#child')) return;
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('parent was clicked, but not on child');
}, true);
function myFunction(event){
   console.log('child was clicked on');
   // when this is clicked, #parent .on(click) also triggers, i don't want that
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="areatext">
  parent
  <div id="input" contenteditable="true" style="min-height:26px;" onkeyup="checkTyping()"></div>
  <div id="child" onclick="myFunction()">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, please check i edited it to be more specific about my code situation, can be the fact i assign the onclick to the child divs dynamically? i mean those child divs are dynamically created with already an onclick="myFunction()" inline.

Comment: Thanks it actually works, i was using the wrong class inside .matches()

Answer (score 2):

If you want parent div's click handler not to be called when child div is clicked, you'll have to add `event.stopPropagation()` in the child div's click event handler.

According to your code:

```js
$('#parent').on('click', function(event){
    $('#input').focus();
    console.log('parent clicked!');
    //event.stopPropagation(); <-- Not needed
});

$('#parent').on('click', '.child', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // ^^^^ Add here
    console.log('child clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="areatext" onkeydown="checkR()">Parent
    <div id="input" contenteditable="true" style="min-height:26px;" onkeyup="checkTyping()"></div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

---

I suggest you read https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing to know how bubbling and capturing works in JavaScript.

Comment: Placed in the myFunction as you suggested, at the end before } closes, console says event.stopPropagation(); is not a function

Comment: @notsure Not sure why that happened, would need to debug your code. But as you are using jQuery, can you use jQuery to add event listener to `child div` instead of html attribute `onclick`. I updated my answer. This should work.

Comment: @notsure although you have marked a answer as accepted, you may still want to check my updated answer. There's a way in jQuery to handle events on dynamically added elements. And you don't have to use html attribute to add event listener.